# Open another workbook with vba that contains all the macros

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Instead of having all the macro's stored in each workbook, we would like to have them stored in one global one. We tried using Personal.xlsb file, however every time excel crashes or system administrator forced restart with excel open it created personal.v.01 ....v.100 files, and they interfered with each other, got corrupted etc.. So instead we are trying to add a small macro to each excel workbook we make which then should open a global excel workbook with all the macros, however it does not open it(normal.xlsb), where is the problem? If I manually run it it works fine, it just does not autorun..

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim sFullName As String
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim wbReturn As Workbook
sFullName = "Z:\Dokumentstyring\normal.xlsb"
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application") 'need to do so to open it in same instance otherwise the global macros can not be called.
Set wbReturn = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename:=sFullName, ReadOnly:=True)
If wbReturn Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Failed to open workbook, maybe z drive is down?"
Else
ThisWorkbook.Activate'Dont know how to pass object to modules, so instead activate it and in createbutton set wb= activeworkbook..
Application.Run ("normal.xlsb!CreateButtons")
End If
End Sub
Public Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim wb As Workbook
For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
If InStr(UCase(wb.Name), "PARTSLIST") > 0 And wb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then Exit Sub
Next wb
On Error Resume Next
Workbooks("normal.xlsb").Close
Workbooks("filter.xlsx").Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using an `AddIn`? all macros in there, then reference it, then `MYAddInName.MyFunctionName(x,y,z)` etc

Comment: Are you the only person who will be opening/using the personal excel file?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav How can you release new version of an addin on the network drive, without having the user to open their excel and link in the new one? No we are 50 people using the personal.xlsb file, hence moving to normal.xlsb file which we open as readonly

Comment: By using the add-in in the network location that will happen naturally.  Sometimes to get a more robust solution in place, takes a bit of effort.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav This is becoming an endless discussion of Add-Ins over centrally provided Master-Excel files which is not really what StackOverflow is striving for: http://stackoverflow.com/tour I am actually also in favor of these centrally provided Master-Excel files. They are much easier to maintain in a corporate environment (if you have Excel installations around the globe in locally managed LANs). Yet, we imported all necessary data into the Master-Excel files and not the macros into the other files. Yet, that's a question for another website. Let's try help the OP resolve the question asked

Comment: I believe the following link might be of interest to you: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/150819-import-module-into-visual-basic-applications-using-visual-basic-applications-macro.html This allows you to import modules (and the VBA code within) from another Excel file into the current Excel file. Let me know if that's what you want and I will gladly provide a full solution. To find out if this is the best solution for your environment (as proposed by @Nathan_Sav) I'd suggest another website or chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Endless, 3 comments?  Would the import require the workbook to not have password protection, or the password contained in the code to unprotect it if needed?  All the best.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav You correctly pointed out what has been already mentioned in the discussion on the linked site. That's why we never had any password protection. Password protection in an Excel file is almost useless (if you allow someone to open the file). But I don't want to comment on that any further or the solution we implemented as this is just part of the discussion I am trying to avoid. Yet, if you are interested I'd be certainly open for an exchange of ideas in a chat (or some other site).

Comment: @Nathan_Sav  Thanks for feedback, I have now succesesfully moved all the macros to z:\normal.xla the problem now is  that how can I update my shapes to link to the addin instead. `ws1.Shapes(tempName).OnAction = "Normal!Custom_Button_Click"` does not work, because the addin  is not visible.

Comment: I also having problem with my bat files now `Set ExcelArgs=CREO,ADDPART

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE16\Excel.exe" /x /r "z:\Dokumentstyring\normal1.XLAM"` does not start my macro in the addin:(  Do I need to make another file test.xlsm which then calls my addIn? And how does addin handle procedure with same names but in different modules?

Comment: Your code would be in the add in, is this the Z drive file?  The code resides in the addin, this will shed some light on it http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut08.htm

Answer (score 1):

You create your addin, as just an empty workbook, holding nothing but the code

Like this

[image]

Then you add a reference to it, in the workbook that you wish to use, in VBA, like this.  My Documents, is a folder on a network drive, not "my documents" local.

[image]

And then you can call like so.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So based on input from @Nathan_Sav and @Ralph I have come to a partly good solution:

I have called my addinn Normal and saved this on Z:Dokumenstyring\Normal.xlam

I then removed all the code in Thisworkbook of Normal:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim ExcelArgs As String
    Dim arg As String
    ExcelArgs = Environ("ExcelArgs")

    'Call deleteMacros.deletePersonalFiles
    'MsgBox ExcelArgs
    If InStr(UCase(ExcelArgs), "CREO,") > 0 Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        If Len(ExcelArgs) > Len("CREO,") Then
            arg = Split(ExcelArgs, ",")(1)
            Call Creo.addNewPartToPartslist(arg)
        End If
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

    If InStr(UCase(ExcelArgs), "DOKLIST,") > 0 Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        If Len(ExcelArgs) > Len("DOKLIST,") Then
            arg = Split(ExcelArgs, ",")(1)
            Call ProsjektListen.dbDumpDocOut(arg)
        End If
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
```

and put this in a new workbook called Z:Dokumenstyring\Creo.xlsm

I have so edited all my bat files(which previously were using personal.xlsb):

```
echo "Launch excel"
Set ExcelArgs=CREO,ADDPART

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE16\Excel.exe" /x /r "z:\Dokumentstyring\Creo.xlsm"
```

So when I run the bat file it adds a parameter to enviroment, start creo.xlsm, which then starts the addin which launch my userform.

So if I now want to update the look of that that userform I do this by modifying the Z:Dokumenstyring\NormalDebug.xlam, then i save a copy which i write over Z:Dokumenstyring\Normal.xlam and I also told every user to not copy the addin to the default location in excel but keep it in Z:Dokumenstyring\Normal.xlam.

My shapes in my excel sheets seems to work with just the macro name in the procedure, however there might be an conflict if two procedures have the same name, but located in different procedures. So I also altered this to

```
ws1.Shapes(tempName).OnAction = "Normal.xlam!Custom_Button_Click"
```

However every click starts a new instance of the addin, how to  avoid this?
 [image]